# Finding urls from text string via php and regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I know the question title looks very repetitive. But some of the solution i did not find here.

**I need to find urls form text string:**

```
$pattern = '`.*?((http|https)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i';

    if (preg_match_all($pattern,$url_string,$matches)) {
        print_r($matches[1]);
    }
```

using this pattern i was able to find urls with `http://` and `https://` which is okey. But i have user input where people add url like `www.domain.com` even `domain.com`

So, i need to validate the string first where i can replace `www.domain.com` `domain.com` with common protocol `http://` before them. Or i need to comeup with more good pattern?

I am not good with regex and don't know what to do.

**My idea** is first finding the urls with `http://` and `https://` the put them in an array then replace these url with space(" ") in the text string then use other patterns for it. But i am not sure what pattern to use.

I am using this `$url_string = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $url_string );` but that removes if any `www.domain.com` or `domain.com` url between two valid url with `http://` or `https://`

If you can help that will be great.

**To make things more clear:**

i need a pattern or some other method where i can find all urls in a text sting. the example of url are:

1. domain.com
2. www.domain.com
3. http://www.domain.com
4. http://domain.com
5. https://www.domain.com
6. https://domain.com

thanks!
 5.

Comment: Are you validating user input from a form with a URL field? Or are you scraping a page/block of text to generate a list of URLs found inside of it? A complete example of the "text string" you are trying to parse might be helpful.

Comment: @baraboom: yes, from user input textbox. where people may input like this twitter : twitter.com/user facebook: http://facebook.com etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pattern = '#(www\.|https?://)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}\S*#i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: Thanks! almost worked!! Still need to find the pattern `domain.com`

Comment: @Sisir replace the `{1}` with a `?` to make the http:// or www optional.

Comment: This does not work for me. I receive an empty results. 
`$pattern = '#(www\.|https?:\/\/){?}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,254}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\S*)#i';
$count = preg_match_all($pattern, 'http://www.Imaurl.com', $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`
 And there is no error from 
`preg_last_error()`

Comment: Copying and pasting this into an interactive PHP shell I also get blank results. Also, the `{2,254}` limit doesn't support domains like `t.co` which are gaining popularity these days. Tried to edit the answer, but an edit must be >6 characters apparently :-( Oh, and I don't think this will match domains like `me-too.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood what you need correctly, but can you use something like this:

```
preg_match('#^.+?://#', $url);
```

to find if there is a protocol specified on the string, and if not just append `http://`