# php regex get first URL from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex in PHP to grab the URLs from a string

```
regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
$string = "lorem ipsum http://google.com lorem ipusm dolor http://yahoo.com/something";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$urls = ($matches[0]);
```

`$urls` returns all the URLs. How can return only the first URL? In this case `http://google.com`.

I'm trying to achieve this without using a foreach loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding urls from text string via php and regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127545/finding-urls-from-text-string-via-php-and-regex)

Comment: @LalitSharma Not a duplicate

Comment: @CyberJunkie an improved version would be `'~https?://[^" ]+~i'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

> preg_match_all — Perform a global regular expression match

Since you are after just one, you should be using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> Perform a regular expression match

```
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
$string = "lorem ipsum http://google.com lorem ipusm dolor http://yahoo.com/something";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Yields:

```
http://google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all()` has a flag parameter which you can use to order the results. The parameter in which you have the variable `$matches` is your results and should be listed in that array.

```
$matches[0][0];//is your first item.
$matches[0][1];//is your second
```

It would be better to use `preg_match()` rather than `preg_match_all()`.

Here's the documentation on `preg_match_all()` for your flags. [Link here!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?(https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/5

```
$re = "/^.*?(https?\\:\\/\\/[^\\\" ]+)/";
$str = "lorem ipsum http://google.com lorem ipusm dolor http://yahoo.com/something";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the 0th index.

```
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
$string = "lorem ipsum http://google.com lorem ipusm dolor http://yahoo.com/something";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$urls = ($matches[0]);
print_r($urls[0]);
```

Output:

```
http://google.com
```